# How can I use API server side to provide datas from my account to a google signed in user?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using angular, google app engine and JAVA on the backend server.
User can authenticate without problem with an opendId connect URL where code is passed back to my server to authenticate.

Now what I wan't to do is send mail to user (refresh password, confirm account mail) and to myself (server error message) with my account `myaccount@gmail.com`.

Also I have sheets I need user to write and read datas to/from. Magically I've made it worked as an installed offline app (only 1 api at a time, I never made the two worked together).

I've tried service account but from a last post somebody explained me that in order to make gmail work I needed a g suite account which I don't have and suggest me to go through oAuth2 authentification. Now the question is how can I implement that in java with a single authentification, I explain, I wan't to authorize app to have access to certain scopes but it should be only be authorized once because I don't want user to have a consent screen popup and even if they had they couldn't authenticate as it is on the behalf of my personnal account. I don't think I can use installed app for a google app engine app but maybe I'm wrong.

just to let you know I have tried lot's of different manners and spent about 3/4 days trying to find a solution without clearly understanding/finding what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated please let me know if you need more explanations or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a few key concepts here.

**DATA**

There are two types of data private user data and public data.  Private user data is owned by a user and there for you must have permission or concent to access it.  Public data is data that is owned by anyone.

**Oauth2**

Oauth2 is the protocol we use to request connect from a user for our applications to access their data.   A user can grant you access to **their** gmail account and **their** google drive account granting you access to the sheets on their account.

**Service accounts**

Service accounts are preapproved dummy users.  As a developers we can create service accounts and grant them access directly to our drive account then the service account will then be able to access to the data without being requiring consent as it already has pre approved access.   (not all google apis support service accounts. gmail (with the exception of gsuite) and YouTube are two that dont)

**What you are trying to do**

However i do not understand why you want to use the users gmail account to send them an email.   If you want to send them an email i would think you would be using your own email system.

If what you are trying to do is use your gmail account to send users of your application emails from YOU.  Then you should consider going directly though the [SMTP](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/imap-smtp) server to your own account.  Having an application that uses the gmail api is one of the scopes that will be flagged by google when you try to get your application approved.   You are going to be going though a lot of red tape with them to show why you need access to a users gmail account.

Comment: thank you for the reply again. I don't wan't to use the users mail to send them mail, I want to use my mail to them mail and to send myself mail for server infos. many Thanks I will look at smtp implementation in java. Best

Comment: I think the SMTP option should work well then.   You will be able to use your login and password.   Too tip use a dummy account while testing so you don't get banned for flooding or something

Comment: @DalmTo it says in documentation of google app engine that smtp is not allowed but I can use mailJet so I'm trying this hope it will work. ;) thanks

Comment: No idea i havent used app engine much.

Comment: no problem I've tried mailjet and it works now. Now I need to implement sheets. Thanks :)